# How can I solve my question in SQL without using a JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Data :                                      Desired result:

class    type    number                     class    rate   score
-------------------------                   ----------------------    
2021      1         5                        2021    0.5      4.8
2021      1         4.6                      2022    0.5      4.6
2021      0         4.8                      
2021     null       null
2022      1         4.2
2022      1         5
2022      0         4.2
2022     null       null
```

1. rate = (type = 1 / all list) group by class.
2. score = AVG(number) where type = 1 group by class.

I want to do like below:

```
SELECT
    a.class, SUM(type) / COUNT(*) AS rate, b.score
FROM
    data as a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         class, AVG(number) AS score 
     FROM
         data 
     WHERE
         type = 1 
     GROUP BY 
         class) AS b ON a.class = b.class
GROUP BY
    class
```

Is there any method to do this without JOIN?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected outcome, both as tables in readable form.

Comment: what's your RDBMS?

Comment: it's mssql  .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some issues should be named:

- Do not use SQL key words like type or number as column names or table names.
- Do not do a division without ruling out possible dividing by zero exceptions.

Anyway, in case your description is correct, you can do following:

```
SELECT class, 
ROUND(AVG(CAST(COALESCE(type,0) AS FLOAT)),2) AS rate,
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN COALESCE(number,0) END),2) AS score
FROM data 
GROUP BY class;
```

You can see here it's working correctly: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fe17da44f915c0b61db8e10ed38bf37)

Some explanations:

- `AVG` will build the average without doing risky divisions.
- `COALESCE` replaces NULL values by zero to make sure the average will be correct.
- `ROUND` makes sure the average will be shown as example as 0.33, not as 0.33333...

If this is not sufficient for you, please be more precise about what exactly you want to do.

Comment: You're welcome, but please don't use comments to only say thank you. If the answer is a sufficient help for you, accept it by clicking on the check mark beside it to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. If it's not, please tell us what you still need to know.

Comment: I use your method and successful, you are awesome.

Comment: this is my firstime to use stackoverflow, i don't know what you mean, i can only find a greyed tick and clicking it to green, is it right ?

Comment: Yes, this was right. Thanks for giving feedback. This will help a lot to learn about Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/tour